# Migration from Academia.SE on design of software website

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm a mod on Academia.SE, and we recently had a question on ["What is the best website design for open source academic software?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/what-is-the-best-website-design-for-open-source-academic-software), would you think it is a good fit for UX.SE? In this case, I could migrate the question, otherwise, if you have any suggestion of where this question would fit, I'd be happy to hear about them!

Answer (score 2):

The asker might be better off asking a more specific question here. As dnbrv mentions that question wouldn't be a good fit here, but maybe something along the lines of:

> "What considerations are there when designing content for those in
>   highly technical fields?"

or

> "How do I structure a website to best serve academic users?"

Even those examples are a bit vague and could be improved, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let the OP know!

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bad question here either. We don't accept requests for examples. And "best" is ambiguous since there isn't a standard.